# I would like to set the Default value for a column to Current Time + 6hrs

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I have a column in an Sql server express table called DepTime which has a Time data type.

I would like to set the Default value for this column to Current Time + 6hrs.

How can I do this.

Thank you

Comment: What db software are you using?

Comment: Server Express edition with advanced tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example for a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
   test varchar(30),
   DepTime datetime  DEFAULT DATEADD(hour, 6, GETDATE())
);
```

or if you already have a table:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable 
   ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeTableSomeName 
   DEFAULT DATEADD(hour, 6, GETDATE()) FOR DepTime;
```