# I want a default on a column(smalldatetime data type) where the time value is current time + 6hrs and updates continuously

Tags: sql-server-express

I want a default on a column(smalldatetime data type) where the time value in each row is current time + 6hrs.

I tried using the Getdate() function but it doesnt update. Instead it just provides a stamp of when the rows were created. You can see that I tried the script in this post. I thought it had worked but when I checked the table the next day the time had never changed.[I would like to set the Default value for a column to Current Time + 6hrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591389/i-would-like-to-set-the-default-value-for-a-column-to-current-time-6hrs)

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: This question does not make any sense.  You asked the question and it was answered.   What exactly do you want?  You say it does not update... do you mean you want the current time +6 from when you query?

Comment: whenever i look at the column i want to see that the time in the column is equal to whatever the current time is + 6 hours. the reason is that the column is used to hold the departure times for flights. the nearest departure time can be 6 hours from the current time as some airlines allow this

Comment: What do you mean by looking at the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following field to your view:

```
DATEADD(hour, 6, GETDATE()) AS Minimum_Departure_Time
```

Since you want it to change when you look at it, there is no reason to put it in the table.  Just put it in your view since the view is dynamically created everytime it is run.

Comment: When i go to update the table and input flight records i want to see that the time in the column is current time +6hrs . if i need to change the time then i will.I have a constraint on the column to make sure times entered must be at least 6hrs in advance .

Comment: what do you mean by "make sure"?  what do you mean by "any time entered"?

Comment: i mean by make sure that no departure time can be less than 6hrs away from current time. by any time entered i mean any departure  time entered in the column for a particular flight.

Comment: so when you are doing an update you want to make sure the departure time is 6 hours from now?  ok, how are you updating the table -- this business rule is more suited for your UI application since it can alert the user for a new value.

Comment: im updating using a view and then editing the rows in the view

Comment: or, add a column like I show in my answer above to your view.

Comment: can you explain what you meant by last comment

Comment: in your view add the codes `DATEADD(hour, 6, GETDATE()) AS Minimum_Departure_Time` to the select list.  This will give you a column with the value you want.

Comment: surely this will give just a static date. what is wrong with updating through  a view?

Comment: I've no idea what you are asking.

Comment: the current date will display initially. what happens when i close the view and reopen it a few days later and need to input new flight records. the date will show the same date from when the getdate function was created

Comment: In my original post i used this to create a default" DEFAULT DATEADD(hour, 6, GETDATE()) FOR DepTime". It resulted in a static date being shown in the column i.e it did not update every day.Whats the difference between the above and the code you are advising

Comment: I'm not suggesting you put the calculation as default value of a table column because TABLES ARE STORED IN A FILE.  I'm suggesting you add the calculation to a view which are EXECUTED AT RUNTIME.  These are basic fundamentals of how SQL databases work.

Comment: very good. thanks for that explanation. i will add it to the view. you said earlier that i should stop updating in the view. is there a problem with doing updating this way.

Comment: My comment about "stop doing that" was slightly in jest.  I'd suggested prior that you put the UI validation logic in the UI layer.  You suggested that you were updating in a view which some how prevented you from having appropriate separation of concerns.  So I said stop since it clearly a bad design if it caused this.It has nothing to do with the details of the technique which while not a leading practice is not inherently wrong.  I still think there is something wrong with validating user input at the database tier. If I were you I would try to find a better design for user data validation.

Comment: I dont have a GUI atm. if u can suggest a better way of updating please do. Btw i have accepted the answer in quotes below. can you post it up as the answer in a new post. i cant do so as i cant answer my own question. it might help somone else lookin for the solution rather than having to read through the comments. thanks for all your help. 
 
"in your view add the codes DATEADD(hour, 6, GETDATE()) AS Minimum_Departure_Time to the select list. This will give you a column with the value you want."